# How to reset all cars to default

Tags: gran-turismo-6

During time, cars are getting extensions like Turbo etc. and from time to time, one is missing to deactivate it after race.

With this tuning equipment active, it can happen that a car is not recognized valid for a particular race. Is there a chance to reset all cars to factory defaults without tuning parts inside garage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're going to have to go through each car one by one in the garage.

A quick way to get the car back to stock tuning parts is to just switch over to another tuning sheet in the car settings page, that is, if you haven't put anything on that tuning page as well.

If not, then you're just going to have to choose Reset to Default on each of the parts settings. Tedious I know, but I don't really understand why you'd want to reset all the cars to stock in the first place.